# Zoopla API returns <h1>Developer Inactive</h1>

Tags: json

I've been trying to use Zoopla's property search API a few days now. First day I used the API, it was straight forward. I registered for a new key, and could do requests via the documentation. Starting yesterday, all the requests I would do would always return a 403 response with the body `<h1>Developer Inactive</h1>`.

I tried creating a new API key but the problem is still the same. Is anyone using the API that can share some knowledge about it? Seems to be deprecated, but I cannot understand how I was getting results from it without issues for a single day.

https://developer.zoopla.co.uk/docs/Property_listings

Comment: is zoopla still working? Do they issue keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is in the process of getting shut down and moved to a new solution.

When signing up to the API, it does not tell you this, which is strange.

When you sign up, the API key will die after 24 hours. However, if you email help@zoopla.co.uk with your email address and API key, they will reinstate the API access.

Comment: I haven't touched the API in a while. I'll accept your answer as it is most practical one.

Answer (score 1):

Ive just hit the exact same issue, trying to create an app using the API, worked great on the first day, but since coming back to my project today it no longer works!

It appears the API is dead and no longer maintained - https://medium.com/@mariomenti/how-not-to-run-an-api-looking-at-you-zoopla-bda247e27d15

Very frustrating.

Comment: Why did it work only the first day though? I tried creating a new account and API key but the result was exactly the same.

Comment: @AlexStyl same here, Created a new account and the same thing happened.
Apparently https://developer.adzuna.com/ is the alternative but i'm yet to go further than making an account